# How to add a link to our wp.org profile from wordpress.org plugin page?

Tags: plugins, repository

We have written a few plugin which are available on the wordpress.org public repository [for example](http://wordpress.org/plugins/export-user-data/) - and I see that other authors have a link to their profile and a count of the plugins they're added, which would be a nice way to show other plugins we're produced - but how to do it?

[image: other plugins]

The sidebar on plugins we released looks like this:

[image: our plugins]

Do we need to add something extra to the readme.txt - or what is the trick - anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link was created automatticly, if you have a profile on wordpress.org.

As example: see my profile: http://profiles.wordpress.org/bueltge/

and see also a plugin of my, same user-slug: http://wordpress.org/plugins/adminimize/

But it is important, that you write case sensitive. The user must include in the readme of the plugin, on the string `Contributors:`. See also a example from the plugin above: http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/adminimize/trunk/readme.txt

```
=== Adminimize ===
Contributors: Bueltge, inpsyde
....
```

Comment: Spot on! - nice one..